# difference between named and anonymous callback function in JS

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I wrote the following practice code to compare the differences between named and anonymous callback function, but the named callback function throws errors, I am wondering why and what's the right way of using named callback function. Thanks for looking

```
friends = ["John", "Mike", "Resch", "Tony"];

friends.forEach(function(value, index) {
  console.log('index of ' + index + ', value is: ' + value);
});

function iterate(value, index)
{
  console.log('index of ' + index + ', value is: ' + value);
}

friends.forEach(iterate(value, index));
```

Comment: It would just be `friends.forEach(iterate)`

Comment: but the defined function 'iterate' has two parameters defined, right?

Comment: Right, you've already defined them with `function iterate(value, index)`. `Array.forEach` expects a reference to a function. It will iterate over its contents, and call that function with two (three) arguments. You define your function to expect two parameters, whether it's named or not. In your first example, you've defined an anonymous function and immediately passed it to `forEach`. In your second example, you defined `iterate`, but you're calling it immediately (with undefined variables) and passing the result (undefined) to `forEach`.

Comment: $.each(friends, iterate(value, index));

Comment: `()` after a function reference **always** calls that function. You don't want to call the function, you want to pass the reference to `.forEach`. Think about it like this: The same way as `bar(42)` is equivalent to `var foo = 42; bar(foo);`, `bar(function() { ... })` is equivalent to `var foo = function() { ... }; bar(foo);`. And `var foo = function() { ... }` is the same as `function foo() { ... }` in this case.

Comment: @SilverBullet: Whatever you trying to say by that comment, it's wrong. Don't confuse the OP.

Comment: There is no "anonymous function". A callback is always passed a function reference, it's never passed the name, so from its perspective, all functions are "anonymous".

Comment: @Flix Kling, its my rights to comment whatever, if you see wrong, say it as wrong. You have no rights to say don't confuse. Mind your words.
Try to give answer to the question, It is not chat office.

Comment: @SilverBullet FelixKling did say it was wrong. You're welcome to comment whatever you want, but when it's wrong, people are going to point it out. Especially if you post something without an explanation that and really isn't different than what the OP already has. By complaining about this, you've started the "chat office"

Comment: I am sorry FelixKling

Answer (score 2):

The last line should be:

```
friends.forEach(iterate);
```

This will pass the `function`, `iterate`, itself so that `.forEach()` can call it and provide arguments for its parameters, `value` and `index`.

By including the additional parenthesis after it, `iterate` is actually being called immediately and would (attempt to) pass `forEach()` its returned value (`undefined` by default).

The errors are likely because `value` and `index` don't exist outside of `iterate()`.

---

For comparison, the equivalent of:

```
friends.forEach(iterate(value, index));
```

with an anonymous function would be:

```
friends.forEach(function(value, index) {
  console.log('index of ' + index + ', value is: ' + value);
}(value, index));
```

Comment: For OP: `forEach` passes the `value` as the first argument, the `index` as the second argument and the array you're going through as the third argument to whatever function you give to it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

> [What is the] difference between named and anonymous callback function in JS

Very little (excluding the code errors pointed out in other answers).

Given:

```
var data = [ ... ];

function foo(value, key, object){ /* do stuff */ }
```

then from the iterator's point of view, there is no difference between:

```
data.forEach(foo);
```

and

```
data.forEach(function (value, key, object){ /* do stuff */ });
```

In both cases, *forEach* is passed a reference to a function object. It doesn't know the name of the function, nor care, it just calls it and passes the required values.

So from the point of view of *forEach*, it doesn't matter whether the function is declared or initialised with a function expression with or without a name, the result is identical.

There is a difference inside the callback. Since in the second case no name is provided in the function expression, it can only reference itself (say for recursion) using *arguments.callee*, which is disliked by some and not available in strict mode.

The fix is to either use a declared function, as in the first example above, or a function expression with a name:

```
data.forEach(function foo (value, key, object){ /* foo references function */ });
```

the latter means that (in ECMA-262 compliant browsers) the name is only available inside the function. However, IE version 8 and lower make named function expressions named properties of the global object (more–or–less global variables), so they are generally avoided:

```
(function foo(){}());

alert(typeof foo);  // function in IE 8 and lower
                    // undefined in compliant browsers
```

Certainly it's rare to use a recursive function in an iterator (but probably not unheard of).